# Is there any way to show user profile of authenticated user after loged in?

Tags: users

I would like to have a block that contains basic profile of authenticated user so that they can see their username, photo, email and log out link.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Author Pane](https://drupal.org/project/author_pane) module to display a block of user information.

> Author Pane is a block of information about a given user, like those
>   typically found on a forum post, but can be used in other places as
>   well. From core, it collects the user picture, name, join date, online
>   status, contact link, and profile information. In addition, any module
>   or theme can feed it more information via the preprocess system. All
>   of this information is then gathered and displayed using a template
>   file.

If you do not want to use this module, then you can create a views to display user information.

- Go to Administration -> Structure -> Views
- Click on "Add new view" link
- Set name for views in "View name" field and select "users" from "show" drop down.
- Click on "Continue and Edit" button
- Create a block display for the views.
- Add "User: Picture", "User: E-mail", "User: Name" and "Global: Custom text (Custom text)".
- Check check-box "Output this field as a link" under "Rewrite results" section for "Global: Custom text" and set "user/logout" as Link path for the field.
- Save the views

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_info().
 */
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks['my-block-id'] = array(
    'info' => t('User Summary'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

 /**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view().
 */
function mymodule_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my-block-id':
     // $block['subject'] = t('Block Name');
      $block['content'] = user_contents();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
function user_contents() {
global $user;
//kpr($user);
$mstr = '';
$mstr .='<div id="first_block" >';
    $mstr .='<fieldset><legend>My Personal Details</legend><div style="margin-top:15px;"><b>User Name.</b></div><div style="">&nbsp;</div><div class="user_name">'.$user->name.'</div>';
    $mstr .='<div style=""><b>User Id:</b> </div><div style="">&nbsp;</div><div id="editme2" class="name1">'.$user->uid.'</div>';
    $mstr .='<div style=""><b>Mail id </b></div><div style="">&nbsp;</div><div class="">'.$user->mail.'</div>';
    $mstr .='<div style=""><b>Timezone </b></div><div style="">&nbsp;</div><div class="">'.$user->timezone.'</div>';
    $mstr .='</div>';

return $mstr;

}
```

this will create a block namely "user summary"

Comment: I got it. Thanks everyone so much! Thank Jayendra Kainthola! This's very helpful, I followed your tut by creating a view to get the block.